# becoming a more popular" or "becoming more populars

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

Can someone explain what is the error here in below sentence?

> Nowadays, several types of music genres, including, rock, hip-hop, R&B and country are becoming more popular across the world and which has sung in various languages.

One of a site which I did validation, it suggesting to change as below.

You either need an article with "more popular" or a plural form. Revise: "becoming a more popular" or "becoming more populars"

But then it looks odd to me if I change as suggested.

Comment: 'Nowadays, several types of music genres, including, rock, hip-hop, R&B and country, are becoming more popular across the world, [and are] being sung in various languages.' Both the suggestions offered above are totally incorrect if the question is stated accurately.

Comment: The grammar of your original looks fine in relation to "are becoming more popular". There are other issues with your sentence, and those might have tripped up the validation site. E.g.: are there *several types of genres* or are there simply *several genres*? Also, did you intend to assert that the types/genres did the singing?

Comment: Come on, folks. popular is an invariable word.

Comment: If your site suggests **anything at all** containing the word "populars", then the site is completely worthless, and you should ignore it.

Comment: "Types of genres" is an awkward phrasing, because "genre" *means* "type", roughly.

Comment: The validation site parsed an unambiguous adjective as a noun, and should be tossed on the trash heap.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to edit the above  example, I would put a colon next to the word "including"—that is to introduce a list of items—and I would put an oxford comma between "R&B" and "country" since they are two different types of music. I would remove the present singular conjugation "has" because the subject being referred to is plural, and would place a comma and a conjuction "and" to  add the phrase "sung in various language". But since "has sung" is in present perfect tense, it doesn't match the tense of the verb used in "are becoming more popular" which is in the present progressive. So i would replace that with "are being sang" to match the tenses. Hence:

Nowadays, several types of music genres including: rock, hip-hop, R&B, and country are becoming more popular across the world, and are being sang in various languages.

I don't know if I make sense but that's how I would want it to go.

Comment: -1 Grammatically, *"are being sang" doesn't work.

Comment: Oh my bad, so the correct is "are being sung"?

Comment: I don't think that matches what the OP wants to express.

Comment: You're welcome :) . I think "are being sung" fits the sentence well. Reading the OP's sentence, though, it looks like he wanted to paint the popularity as a 'continuing' trend and the multilingual nature as something established in the past.

Comment: @Dyeyyuen    I understand "has been" is wrong. Can I use " have been" instead "are being sung"?

Comment: sing, sang, sung

Answer (score 0):

> Nowadays, several types of music genres, including, rock, hip-hop, R&B and country are becoming more popular across the world and which has sung in various languages.

As Lambie has commented, there is no *populars*.

My suggestion is

> Nowadays, several[ ]music genres, including[ ]rock, hip-hop, R&B[,] and country[,] are becoming more popular across the world and are being sung in various languages.

I have

a. deleted *types of* which is redundant, as stangdon has commented

b. completed the *bracketing comma* pair for the appositive "including...and country"

c. deleted the comma before *rock*

Notes
c. Three *listing commas* are used to separate the four nouns in the series; the comma after *R&B* is optional, and its use depends on region.  The colon should not be used if the introductory expression for a list is not a complete sentence.

> Colons with Lists

> Rule 1: Use the colon after a complete sentence to introduce a list of items when introductory words such as namely, for example, or that is do not apply or are not appropriate.

> Rule 2: A colon usually does not precede a list unless it follows a complete sentence.

[Grammarbook](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/colons/colons/)

[Sussex](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma)

Answer (score 0):

If you just change "which has" to "are", the sentence is fine.

That said,

> several types of music genres, including

is awkward, and I would probably say something like,

> many music genres, including...

or simply

> music genres, such as...